# If an object property doesn't exist, skip over it

Tags: javascript, object

I am currently working with the New York Times api, and pulling an image from each post. Currently I am getting a " TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null" because of of the properties is set to null, while every other post has info to fill my img src tag. I am using vanilla js.
Here is the API property that is null - every other post has an array I can pull from.

multimedia: null

How can I filter or write code to have JS ignore if a property is set to null, so I dont get this error. Thank you

```
function renderSingleArticle(article) {
  const url = `${article.multimedia[0].url}`;

  return `
  <div class="column-third">
    <div class="article-card">
      <h2 class="news-title">${article.title}</h2>
      <img src=${url} alt="CurrentNews">
      <div class="article-card-text>
        <p class="abstract">${article.abstract}</p>
        <a href=${article.short_url} target="blank">Click here to read more...</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
`;
```

Comment: no " Cannot read property '0' of null" mean this object is null, not his property, because null elements can't have any property

Answer (score 1):

You could create the conditional on the `<img` tag itself which takes care of all your logic at the top.

```
function renderSingleArticle(article) {
  const img = article.multimedia && article.multimedia.length>0 && article.multimedia[0].url ? `<img src="${article.multimedia[0].url}" alt="CurrentNews">` : ''; 
  return `
  <div class="column-third">
    <div class="article-card">
      <h2 class="news-title">${article.title}</h2>
      ${img}
      <div class="article-card-text>
        <p class="abstract">${article.abstract}</p>
        <a href=${article.short_url} target="blank">Click here to read more...</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`` const url = article && article.multimedia[0] ? `${article.multimedia[0].url}` : ''; ``

`{url && <img src=${url} alt="CurrentNews">}`

You can implement the conditional operator in JS:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

The idea is when you got an empty/null value, then you don't need to render them to avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use an `||` with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```js
let article = { multimedia: null };
console.log((article.multimedia || [])[0]?.url)
```